# Changing part of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a little problem with my useState Hook. I want to change only "answer".

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState({
    question1: { answer: "1", isCorrect: false },
    question2: { answer: "1", isCorrect: false },
    question3: { answer: "1", isCorrect: false },
    question4: { answer: "1", isCorrect: false }
  });
```

```
const onChange = e => {
    setQuestions({
      ...questions,
      [e.target.name]: { answer: e.target.value }
    });
  };
```

This function works, but `isCorrect` disappear.

I know I can use `[e.target.name]: { answer: e.target.value, isCorrect: false}`
but I want a previous state. `...isCorrect` doesn't work. It shoud be so easy but I cant find solucion. I wish someone can help me with that.

Comment: `[e.target.name]: { ...questions[e.target.name], answer: e.target.value }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Comment: This is because you are replacing the `questionN` object with a new object. BTW, if you are using numbers on your key names, you should most likely use an array instead of an object.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice numbers are temporally

Comment: @Emile Bergeron Yes, it does. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use spread syntax for the nested values too and override the answer key

```
const onChange = e => {
    setQuestions({
      ...questions,
      [e.target.name]: { ...questions[e.target.name], answer: e.target.value }
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

`spread` the original object and overwrite `answer`

```
   const onChange = e => {
    setQuestions({
      ...questions,
      [e.target.name]: { ...questions[e.target.name], answer: e.target.value }
    });
  };
```